# what is an 'outstanding' frame?

Tags: networking, frame, network-protocols, go-back-n

What is meant by *outstanding* frame ?

I read this term while studying [`GBN protocol`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-Back-N_ARQ) .

From wikipedia:

> frames since the first lost frame are *outstanding*, and
>   will go back to sequence number

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess these are the packets whose acknowledgment is awaiting. someone confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

I think *outstanding* here means - still waiting for acknowledgement.

All the successful frames were passed successfully and the reciever sent an acknowledgement for them, but it didn't recieve the lost frame and ignore the following frames, so these frames are still *outstanding*

Answer (score 0):

The **outstanding frames** are those frames which the source had sent from **inside the window and their acknowledgement has not yet come**.

Suppose The window size is 4 then source will send 4 packets at a time and these packets are not been acknowledged and are still inside the window so these are the outstanding frames.

In your case this line means that if the first frame sent by the source is lost or does not get an acknowledgement then It would send those outstanding frames again form the start because destination hasnt recieved the frames in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Security [Encyclopedia](https://www.windows-security.org/285abcc1f95b468bcb04c618c87c07a0/limit-outstanding-packets)

> "Outstanding packets" are packets that the Packet Scheduler has submitted to a network adapter for transmission but which have not yet been sent.