# Outstanding frames in packets

Tags: packet

I came across this term "Outstanding frames" while studying about packet transmission between client and server, but I have doubts around this term.
There is an older question on the same topic but it doesn't seem to have a definitive answer in it: [what is an 'outstanding' frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281682/what-is-an-outstanding-frame)

I got 2 possible definitions of what it can be:

Packets which are queued up for transmission but not yet sent **and**

packets sent to client but Acknowledgement has not been received yet for the packets.

So which is the correct meaning for the term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second definition is more accurate: outstanding frames refer to packets that have been sent to the client, but for which an acknowledgement has not yet been received by the server. This means that the server is still waiting for confirmation that the packets were successfully received by the client. In contrast, packets that are queued up for transmission but not yet sent are referred to as "pending frames."